# How to include a custom thumbnail with my WordPress plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, updates, logo

I am developing a WordPress plugin and I would like to show a custom logo/thumbnail on the "WordPress Updates" screen like other plugins do.

What do I need to do to get this to happen?

Right now it just shows the default "plug" icon:

[image: Admin Panel Screenshot]

Comment: What keeps you from looking into the other plugins yourself?

Comment: @leymannx I looked and there's nothing there. No image files, and no references to the images in the readme.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation.

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-assets/#plugin-icons

Filenames #Filenames
  Normal: icon-128x128.(png|jpg)
  High-DPI (Retina): icon-256x256.(png|jpg)
  SVG: icon.svg

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already had the 256 icon in place. However, I added the 128 and the .svg to no effect.

Comment: where did you add them  ?

Comment: Just so you know, if you are distributing your plugin, it _must_ be open source. You don't have to host it on WordPress.org, but since themes and plugins are derivative of WordPress you still need to abide by the terms of the GPL.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out - I am using the Freemius plugin framework, and they have a specific place to put a custom logo - the `{/freemius/assets/img/{slug}.png` path in the plugin folder. Presumably, this logo file is picked up by the framework's PHP code and put in the proper place so that it is shown on the update screen.

I don't know how one would go about doing this if they were developing from scratch and not on Freemius, but this is what worked for me.